# How does an architect 'make' a blueprint of a building? Is there a word for describing it? Or should I just use 'make'?

Tags: word-request

How does an architect 'make' a blueprint of a building? Is there a word for describing it? Or should I just use 'make'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on this [site](https://www.pcc.edu/programs/architectural-design/employment.html):

> "The **architectural drafter** is a skilled technician who designs and/or develops the working drawings required to guide the construction of buildings. Architectural drafters are concerned with building designs, site, floor and foundation plans, elevations, building sections and details, cost estimates, specification writing, code and zoning applications, renderings and perspectives, models of building, structural design, environmental system design and computer applications."

You can therefore use the verbs *design*, *draw*, *draft*, etc., (I personally would use 'draft')

e.g., An architect drafts the blueprint of the building.

Comment: +1. https://www.google.com/search?q=%22drafted%20a%20blueprint%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en